# Timeline View Only

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, timeline

I created a Timeline webpart for everyone to view; however, I don't want them to be able to click and open a task from the timeline. I've removed all navigation from the page, so they can only see the timeline. 
How do I block the popup or prevent the task from opening? I already tried "view only" access, but they can still open the task.

Answer (score 0):

Someone else may be able to provide a coded solution to disable the flyout menu, but I have a no-code hack.

My assumption:  The users you are presenting the timeline to only need read access to tasks in a view and/or the timeline.  They do need to view the New, Edit, or Display forms associated with the Tasks list.

Hack:  (NOTE:  This will not prevent users from clicking a task and launching the flyout menu with the "Open" option, but it will prevent them from seeing the Display form.)
Go to the Tasks list.  On the ribbon, in the "List" tab, click "Form Web Parts" and select "Default Display Form."  Go to the web part settings and in the "Advanced" section, in the "Target Audience" field, enter only the site owners group and save your changes. This hides the task's columns in the display form to everyone except the owners.  If you want, you can add a CEWP to the page with text noting that the "Open" feature is not available to site users.

[image]